# How can I merge two arrays by key?

Tags: ansible

I have two variables - json arrays in playbook and want to merge it in one, and combine values "by key" using Ansible.
Example below:
From:

```
 "msg": [
        {
            "mount_point": "/mnt/data/",
            "pvs": "9b802bd8-16a2-4558-9049-f326e8cf84b8"
        },
        {
            "mount_point": "/mnt/data/",
            "pvs": "992213e8-b7de-4270-adc0-dbce7d2423a1"
        },
        {
            "mount_point": "/mnt/data/",
            "pvs": "c855a196-c17a-4df4-b77d-5eedfa470204"
        },
        {
            "mount_point": "/mnt/log/",
            "pvs": "c855a196-c17a-4df4-b77d-5eedfa470204"
        },
        {
            "mount_point": "/mnt/log/",
            "pvs": "c855a196-c17a-4df4-b77d-5eedfa470204"
        },
    ]
```

to(combine strings by key "mount_point"):
Expected result:

```
"msg": [
        {
            "mount_point": "/mnt/data/",
            "pvs": 
                - "9b802bd8-16a2-4558-9049-f326e8cf84b8"
                - "992213e8-b7de-4270-adc0-dbce7d2423a1"
                - "c855a196-c17a-4df4-b77d-5eedfa470204"
        },
        {
            "mount_point": "/mnt/log/",
            "pvs": 
                - "c855a196-c17a-4df4-b77d-5eedfa470204"
                - "c855a196-c17a-4df4-b77d-5eedfa470204"
        }
    ]
```

I tried different combinations, also using external file, but nothing.

Comment: Please share the code you have tried with, then we can both help you troubleshoot and better understand the issues you are having. Remember to add any specific information or errors involving your attempt. To learn more about how the [SO] community can help you, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Can you reduce the example to a shorter one, and also please include the expected exact result

Comment: My 2 cent for your next post: choose your tags wisely. This has nothing to do with python directly and this is mainly why you got your downvotes (because such a question for python only is trivial, not as much for ansible if you're not yet accustomed to existing filters).

Comment: Ok, I’ll be more accurate

Answer (score 2):

The following playbook with intermediate steps and debugging for clarity gives what you expect. Non exhaustive list of documentation to read:

- [Jinja2 `groupby` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.groupby)
- [`ansible.builtin.zip` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/zip_filter.html)
- [Jinja2 `map` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map)
- [`ansible.builtin.dict2items` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/dict2items_filter.html)
- [`community.general.dict` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/dict_filter.html)

The demo playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    msg: [
           {
               "mount_point": "/mnt/data/",
               "pvs": "9b802bd8-16a2-4558-9049-f326e8cf84b8"
           },
           {
               "mount_point": "/mnt/data/",
               "pvs": "992213e8-b7de-4270-adc0-dbce7d2423a1"
           },
           {
               "mount_point": "/mnt/data/",
               "pvs": "c855a196-c17a-4df4-b77d-5eedfa470204"
           },
           {
               "mount_point": "/mnt/log/",
               "pvs": "c855a196-c17a-4df4-b77d-5eedfa470204"
           },
           {
               "mount_point": "/mnt/log/",
               "pvs": "c855a196-c17a-4df4-b77d-5eedfa470204"
           }
       ]

    _grouped_entries: "{{ msg | groupby('mount_point') }}"
    _mount_points: "{{ _grouped_entries | map(attribute=0) }}"
    _pvs: "{{ _grouped_entries | map(attribute=1) | map('map', attribute='pvs') }}"
    _mount_points_pvs_dict: "{{ _mount_points | ansible.builtin.zip(_pvs) | community.general.dict  }}"
    mount_points_pvs_list: "{{ _mount_points_pvs_dict | ansible.builtin.dict2items(key_name='mount_point', value_name='pvs')}}"

  tasks:
    - name: Group entries in mount_point / entries tuples
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: _grouped_entries

    - name: Extract the list of mount points
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: _mount_points

    - name: Extract the list of pvs for each mount points in the same order
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: _pvs

    - name: Create a dict with mount points as keys and pvs list as values
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: _mount_points_pvs_dict

    - name: Transform dict to expected list
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: mount_points_pvs_list
```

And the demo playbook run:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [Group entries in mount_point / entries tuples] ***********************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "_grouped_entries": [
        [
            "/mnt/data/",
            [
                {
                    "mount_point": "/mnt/data/",
                    "pvs": "9b802bd8-16a2-4558-9049-f326e8cf84b8"
                },
                {
                    "mount_point": "/mnt/data/",
                    "pvs": "992213e8-b7de-4270-adc0-dbce7d2423a1"
                },
                {
                    "mount_point": "/mnt/data/",
                    "pvs": "c855a196-c17a-4df4-b77d-5eedfa470204"
                }
            ]
        ],
        [
            "/mnt/log/",
            [
                {
                    "mount_point": "/mnt/log/",
                    "pvs": "c855a196-c17a-4df4-b77d-5eedfa470204"
                },
                {
                    "mount_point": "/mnt/log/",
                    "pvs": "c855a196-c17a-4df4-b77d-5eedfa470204"
                }
            ]
        ]
    ]
}

TASK [Extract the list of mount points] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "_mount_points": [
        "/mnt/data/",
        "/mnt/log/"
    ]
}

TASK [Extract the list of pvs for each mount points in the same order] *****************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "_pvs": [
        [
            "9b802bd8-16a2-4558-9049-f326e8cf84b8",
            "992213e8-b7de-4270-adc0-dbce7d2423a1",
            "c855a196-c17a-4df4-b77d-5eedfa470204"
        ],
        [
            "c855a196-c17a-4df4-b77d-5eedfa470204",
            "c855a196-c17a-4df4-b77d-5eedfa470204"
        ]
    ]
}

TASK [Create a dict with mount points as keys and pvs list as values] ******************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "_mount_points_pvs_dict": {
        "/mnt/data/": [
            "9b802bd8-16a2-4558-9049-f326e8cf84b8",
            "992213e8-b7de-4270-adc0-dbce7d2423a1",
            "c855a196-c17a-4df4-b77d-5eedfa470204"
        ],
        "/mnt/log/": [
            "c855a196-c17a-4df4-b77d-5eedfa470204",
            "c855a196-c17a-4df4-b77d-5eedfa470204"
        ]
    }
}

TASK [Transform dict to expected list] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "mount_points_pvs_list": [
        {
            "mount_point": "/mnt/data/",
            "pvs": [
                "9b802bd8-16a2-4558-9049-f326e8cf84b8",
                "992213e8-b7de-4270-adc0-dbce7d2423a1",
                "c855a196-c17a-4df4-b77d-5eedfa470204"
            ]
        },
        {
            "mount_point": "/mnt/log/",
            "pvs": [
                "c855a196-c17a-4df4-b77d-5eedfa470204",
                "c855a196-c17a-4df4-b77d-5eedfa470204"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```